# JavaScript - validating for only numeric/alphabet

Tags: javascript, validation

i know there a lot of similar threads to the topic line, so i'll get straight to the point to clarify my issue. Have a simply form in which i'm validating, in which testing for empty fields runs perfectly, and after following various other forum posts, have attempted implementing tests for numeric or alphabetic input, but the functions simply won't function.

Here is a snippet of my working NotEmpty function:

```
 function validateNotEmpty( input, id )
     {

        var errorDisplay =  document.getElementById( id );
        var notEmpty;
        if ( input == "" ) // check if input is empty
        {
           errorDisplay.innerHTML = "This is a requiered field";
           notEmpty = false; // update return value
        } // end if
        else
        {
           errorDisplay.innerHTML = ""; // clear the error area
           notEmpty = true; // update return value
        } // end else

        return notEmpty; // return whether the input is empty

     }// end function validateNotEmpty
```

And the following are my two (not working numeric/alphabet testers):

```
function validateNotNumber(input, id) 
    {
            var errorDisplay =  document.getElementById( id );
            var notNumber;

            for (var i=0;i<input.value.length;i++){
            temp=input.value.substring(i,i+1);
                console.log(temp);
            if (digits.indexOf(temp)==-1){
                errorDisplay.innerHTML = "Sorry, this section can not have numbers";
                notNumber =  false;
               }
            else
             {
               errorDisplay.innerHTML = ""; // clear the error area
               notEmpty = true; // update return value
             } // end else
         }
         return notNumber;
    }



function validateNotLetter(input, id) 
            {
                var errorDisplay =  document.getElementById( id );
                var notLetter;

                for (var i=0;i<input.value.length;i++){
                temp=input.value.substring(i,i+1);
                    console.log(temp);
                if (alphabets.indexOf(temp)==-1){
                    errorDisplay.innerHTML = "Sorry, this section can not have letter";
                    notLetter =  false;
                   }
                else
                 {
                   errorDisplay.innerHTML = ""; // clear the error area
                   notLetter = true; // update return value
                 } // end else
             }
             return notLetter;
        }
```

On top of this, this is how i am calling the javascript functions from my form:

```
<td width="135" valign="top">
                          <input size="15" type="text" name="Full_Name"  value="" onblur = "validateNotNumber( this.value, 'nameError' )"/>
                         <p> <span id = "nameError" class = "errorMessage"></span> </p>
</td>
```

Thanks for any help/pointers, still pretty new to JavaScript, so wrapping my head around validation has been pretty complicated.

Comment: A regex would simplify your code.    If you take some time and clean up your post, and create a simple code example we will help.

Comment: issue in your validateNotNumber function is while looping you are using input.value.length instead only use input.length same goes for this line also temp=input.value.substring(i,i+1); plus you are using digits which is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/3z82efft/) to help you start.

I updated it to basically do what you want but to use regexes to detect numbers, letters, etc.

Sample of one of them:

```
 function validateNotLetter(input, id) {
   var errorDisplay = document.getElementById(id);

   var value = input || '';

   var letterRegex  = /\D+/i;
    var hasALetter = letterRegex.test(value);
   if(hasALetter){
     errorDisplay.innerHTML = "Sorry, this section can not have letter";;
   }else{
    errorDisplay.innerHTML = "";
   }

   return notLetter;
 }
```

Regex's are powerful.  Tons of resources online:

1. https://regex101.com/ - Place to test out regex's
2. https://regexone.com/ - Place to learn

Answer (score 1):

This is overcomplicated way. You should definitly try some regex e.g.

```js
    var alphanumeric = "someStringHere";
    var myRegEx  = /[^a-z\d]/i;
    var isValid = !(myRegEx.test(alphanumeric));
    console.log(isValid);
```

or a function:

```
function isValid(str) {
  var myRegEx  = /[^a-z\d]/i;
  return !(myRegEx.test(str));
}
```